# Return two tables, nested together, with one request

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a project management app with Projects, Tasks and Assignments.

```
Project
has_many :tasks

Task
belongs_to :project
has_many :assignments

Assignment
belongs_to :task
belongs_to :user
```

I want to be able to GET all of a Project's Tasks and Assignments with just one request.

Currently I have to request each Task's Assignments, which could be very inefficient if a user has more than just a few Tasks.

Comment: Is this per user or per project?

Comment: Per project. I'd like to get all of a project's tasks and assignments in one query.

Comment: are you using JSON by any chance? If so, you can override as_json and use includes.

Comment: `@project.as_json(:include => {:tasks => {:include => :assignments}})`

Comment: @achabacha322 this works! thanks! is there a way to do it as ruby objects, or does it have to done as_json?

Comment: with Ruby objects you will probably have to loop through the records you get using`.includes` like @Swards said

Comment: @achabacha322 thanks so much. If you want to submit an answer I will accept it. Btw, where can I learn more about this approach?

Comment: @zapatos - would love to know what you're doing that's different than the answer I gave.

Comment: @Swards using the method above, `@project.as_json(:include => {:tasks => {:include => :assignments}})` which gives the project with nested tasks and deliverables.

Comment: @zapatos - sure, but that will run subqueries with each include which I thought you were looking to avoid.  If you want to do it all in one query and avoid n+1 than you'll need to do the includes when the project object is initialized. Json is just another rendering option (like html) from Ruby objects, but if those objects don't already have their associations loaded, you'll be running multiple sub queries, which can be inefficient.  This is easy to confirm for yourself, compare each in console with/without the includes and you'll see the queries run before the output is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

If you do something like this, Rails will figure out the best queries to run

```
# Assuming params[:id] is the project id.
@project = Project.includes(:tasks => :assignments).find(params[:id])
```

So when you ask for `@project.tasks` and the loop through each task with `task.assignments`, the associations are already loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. When I run that in the console, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'includes' for @project`

Comment: Sorry, that was a dumb mistake, the @project needs to be assigned.

Comment: This does not return the assignments.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If you loop through the tasks and associated assignments, they should all be loaded and cause no further queries.

Comment: I'm looking for the tasks and assignments to be return in one payload.

Comment: Yeah - they should be there.  When you say payload, is this a json payload in an API?  If you're using them in views, you have them available.  You can force a single query or multiple queries with `.eager_load` or `.preload` instead of `.includes`, which will choose.  This may be useful reference http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Answer (score 1):

Add a *has many through* to the `Project` model like so:

```
has_many :tasks
has_many :assignments, through: :tasks
```

Now you'll be able to call `@project.assignments` to get ALL assignments of that project or `@project.assignments.uniq` to list unique assignments (that don't repeat) in the event that an assignment would be under two tasks if you expand your associations to include that functionality.

Comment: This returns just the assignments. I'd like to get all the tasks and assignments together, with the assignments nested in the tasks.

Comment: @zapatos, how do you plan on displaying the combined array of objects in your view?